# How to make something similar to Time-Machine in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I want to implement something similar to MAC OS X Time Machine in terms of having time-line on the page side and then clicking on a specific day will pull a page from the server.

I have good experience with Ruby on Rails. I'm less experienced with GUI design and was wondering what in your opinion is the optimum way to do something like that. Couple of ideas came to mind:
- Use Adobe Flex (or maybe Silverlight?)
- Use JQuery (or similar JavaScript library)
- Use something like Objective JavaScript

It would be nice if you can recommend something. Also it would be if you know of similar open-source project or plugin that might help.

Thanks,

Tam

Comment: You just want a page of links to archived versions of the page?

Comment: I could picture this being an interesting user experience for a wiki history...not sure of the practicality, but what does that matter? :)

Comment: I want more like a easy view of historical content and I think Time Machine got it right. yeah Wiki history would be good idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to go ahead and say Flash/Flex, but Flash does not have full css/html support to render out complex pages, so unless you combined the effect with JavaScript/CSS/HTML and some clever overlays, you wouldn't be able to do it.